# What is causing a NoSuchMethodErrorImplementation?

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I am getting the following error:

```
Stack Trace: #0      NoSuchMethodErrorImplementation._throwNew (dart:core-patch:641:3)
#1      init_autogenerated (http://127.0.0.1:3030/C:/dev/CalendarDatePicker/CalendarDatePicker/web/out/CalendarDatePicker.dart:43:26)
#2      main (http://127.0.0.1:3030/C:/dev/CalendarDatePicker/CalendarDatePicker/web/out/CalendarDatePicker.html_bootstrap.dart:7:30)
```

Here is my view code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CalendarDatePicker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CalendarDatePicker.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <element name="calendar" constructor="Calendar" extends="div">
      <template>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Sun</th>
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thu</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
            <th>Sat</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </template>
    </element>
    <div is="calendar"></div>
    <script type="application/dart" src="CalendarDatePicker.dart"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dart.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/client/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my main script:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';


void main() {

}

class Calendar extends WebComponent
{

}
```

It is failing in the auto-generated code on this line:

```dart
new Calendar.forElement(__e0)
  ..created_autogenerated() //Exception: No such method: 'Calendar.forElement'
  ..created()
  ..composeChildren();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change the `<element>` `name` so that it starts with an `x-`:

```html
<element name="x-calendar" constructor="Calendar" extends="div">
```

and the `<div is="calendar"></div>` to:

```html
<x-calendar></x-calendar>
```

Or you can use the `is=` syntax, if you prefer.

These are recommended changes, but don't solve the problem.  The way this would work is if

```dart
class Calendar extends WebComponent {}
```

went inside the `<element>` itself (as a sibling of `<template>`) inside a `<script>` tag.

The other way would be to isolate your component code in a separate file and explicitly import it using the correct syntax. Something like this:

```html
<link rel="components" href="calendar_component.html">
```

So, I've broken down your app into 4 files. `calendarPicker.html`, the main html file,  looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CalendarDatePicker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calendarDatePicker.css">
    <link rel="components" href="calendar_component.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <x-calendar></x-calendar>

    <script type="application/dart" src="calendarDatePicker.dart"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://dart.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/client/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`calendarDatePicker.dart` is pretty minimal:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';

void main() {}
```

Your component code (`calendar_component.dart`) has this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <element name="x-calendar" constructor="CalendarComponent" extends="div">
      <template>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Sun</th>
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thu</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
            <th>Sat</th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </template>
      <script type="application/dart" src="calendar_component.dart"></script>
    </element>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the accompanying dart file (`calendar_component.dart`) has the component class in it:

```dart
import 'package:web_ui/web_ui.dart';

class CalendarComponent extends WebComponent {}
```

Hope this helps. I built the app using the code you provided and duplicated the error; then, I rebuilt it with the code shown here. It runs without any errors.

Answer (score 2):

As Shailen said, the `<element>` tag should contain a `<script>` tag (possibly with src= attribute) that defines Calendar type.

More info here:
http://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-web-components/#component-declaration

I also filed bug https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/issues/297, because you shouldn't get a noSuchMethod error :)